# php function returns string(6) "Object"

Tags: php, function, wsdl, soap-client

i have a class which uses a wsdl file,

```
class myAPI{    

        public function Authenticate($id,$password){  

            $opts = array('location' => 'http://xx',
              'uri' => 'urn:xxx',
              'trace' => 1);
            $client2 = new SOAPClient(null, $opts);

            $quote = $client2 ->__soapCall('createsession', array(''));  
            $session = $quote -> sessionid;
            $sessionOk = $quote -> result;
            if ($sessionOk == 0)
            {     
                    $shaStr1 =  $id.$password;
                    $shaStr1 =  sha1($shaStr1);
                    $shaStr2 = $session.strtolower($shaStr1);
                    $shaStr2 =  strtoupper(sha1($shaStr2));


                    $xml_params = '<ns1:loginRequest> <ns1:initiator>'.$id.'</ns1:initiator>  <ns1:pin>'.$shaStr2.'</ns1:pin>  <ns1:sessionid>'.$session.'</ns1:sessionid> </ns1:loginRequest>';


                    try 
                    { 
                        $soapVar = new SoapVar($xml_params, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null); 

                    }                   
                    catch(Exception $e)
                    {       
                        $message = $e->getMessage(); 
                        $err = array (
                           'result' => '999',
                           'transid' => '0',
                           'msg' => $message
                        );

                        return (object) $err;            
                    }

                    try 
                    {  
                        $result = $client2->login(new SoapParam($soapVar, 'login'));   

                        $resint = $result -> result;
                        $restrans = $result -> transid;   


                        return (object) array (
                           'result' => $resint,
                           'transid' => $restrans,
                           'msg' => 'Session Created',
                           'session' => $session
                        ); 


                    }  
                    catch(Exception $e) 
                    {  
                        $message = $e->getMessage(); 
                        $err = array (
                           'result' => '999',
                           'transid' => '0',
                           'msg' => $message
                        );

                        return (object) $err;       
                    } 


            }   
            else //session is invalid
            {
                    $err = array (
                           'result' => '999',
                           'transid' => '0',
                           'msg' => 'Invalid session'
                        );

                return (object) $err;  
            }       

        }
    ?>
```

Im using a wsdl which is pointed to my service.php file which has :
service.php

```
<?php 
include("myAPI.php"); 
if(!extension_loaded("soap")){ 
  dl("php_soap.dll"); 
} 
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0"); 
$server = new SoapServer("service.wsdl");

function login($info){
    $globeapi = new GlobeAPI;
    $loginResult = $globeapi->Authenticate($info -> id,$info -> password);  

     return $loginResult;

}

$server->AddFunction("login");   
$server->handle();

?>
```

when i try to use them using the code below all i received is string(6) "Object",if i try to use an array it returns string(5) "Array"
what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
client = new SoapClient('http://xxxx/service.wsdl',
array(
'trace' =>true,
'exceptions' => 0,
'connection_timeout' => 500000,
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_BOTH,
'keep_alive' => false,
));

$response = $client->login('xxx','2222'); 
var_dump($response);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like the `SoapClient` class converts the result to a string.

Comment: but how can i make it return the object?

Comment: Check the documentation of the SoapClient class you're using.

Comment: Thank you but, if i directly use the code in myAPI.php, i am able to return the object properly, but when im using the service.php, that is where my problem appears, so i dont think the issue is with the soapclient class i am using.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to inform everyone that might be encountering the same problem. I found out that my problems lies in my WSDL file. I didnt provide a xsd:complexType thus all i was returning was a string. What i did is to declare the xsd:complexType  like this

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:xxx"
>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
    <xsd:complexType name="resultInfo">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="transid" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="session" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

after that i changed all my responsetype from "xsd:string"  to my complextype which is "xsd:resultInfo". Then i was able to return the objects needed in my php page.